# How can I access a constant defined in one initializer file into another initializer file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have defined a YAML file like this `throttling_request.yml`

```
logged_in_user:
  watching_timespan: 60
  allowed_requests:  60
  blocking_timespan: 300

non_logged_in_user:
  watching_timespan: 300
  allowed_requests:  300
```

I load the YML file in `config/intializers/throttle_config.rb`

```
config = YAML.load_file('config/throttling_request.yml').with_indifferent_access
THROTTLE_REQ_NON_LOGGED_IN = config[:non_logged_in_user]
THROTTLE_REQ_LOGGED_IN     = config[:logged_in_user]
```

But I want to access this constant `THROTTLE_REQ_NON_LOGGED_IN` into another initializer file `config/initializers/rack_attack.rb`

```
  configs = ::THROTTLE_REQ_NON_LOGGED_IN

  # Throttle all requests by IP (20rpm)
  #
  # Key: "rack::attack:#{Time.now.to_i/:period}:req/ip:#{req.ip}"
  throttle('req/ip', limit: configs[:allowed_requests], period: configs[:watching_timespan]) do |req|
    req.ip unless req.path.start_with?('/assets')
  end
```

I could not able to load with or without scope resolution operator `::` for constant `THROTTLE_REQ_NON_LOGGED_IN`. I want to use constants `THROTTLE_REQ_LOGGED_IN` for my other class and `THROTTLE_REQ_NON_LOGGED_IN` in rack attack config. So I don't want to mix up calling this constant in rack attack initializer file.

Please let me know if any other information needed from me.

Comment: Can this be of any help, the `config_for` method? https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html#method-i-config_for

Comment: @Eyeslandic `config_for` is nice but I am using rails 3 app. It's available only rails 4.2 plus versions.

Comment: Ok. Nothing stopping you from using the code though if you like https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L226

Comment: sure I will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Suggested solution**

In your `application.rb` do the following:

```
::THROTTLE_CONFIG = YAML.load_file('config/throttling_request.yml').with_indifferent_access
```

Now, anywhere in the project, including `config/initializers/rack_attack.rb` you can do:

```
THROTTLE_CONFIG[:non_logged_in_user]
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is again rails standard to put a constant in `application.rb`

Comment: @punitcse I've been using this for the last 3~4 years; never had an issue with it.